# Why do integers have to be converted to strings before they can be used to access items in a collection?

Tags: collections, vb6

I am new to VB in general. I am going through some old VB code and I see statements like -

```
  Addr.AddrType(CStr(0)).A_Type = " "
```

Why does the integer 0 have to be converted to a string?

Note that Addr is defined as

```
 Public Addr As clsAddressDetail
```

AddrType is defined as a collection

```
 Public AddrType As New Collection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Collection` class being used here has what is effectively an [overloaded indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a82kxee5%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). My emphases:

> Returns a specific element of a Collection object **either by position
>   or by key**. Read-only.
>
> ```
> Default Public ReadOnly Property Item( _
> ByVal { Key As String | Index As Integer | Index As Object } _ ) As Object
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> Key
>
> A unique String expression that specifies a key string that can be used, instead of a positional index, to access an element of the
>   collection. Key must correspond to the Key argument specified when the
>   element was added to the collection.
>
> Index
>
> (A) A numeric expression that specifies the position of an element of the collection. Index must be a number from 1 through the value of
>   the collection's Count Property (Collection Object). **Or** (B) An Object
>   expression that specifies the position or key string of an element of
>   the collection.

So, if you ask for `AddrType(0)`, you are asking for the zeroth member of the collection, which for this 1-based collection is an error. But if you ask for `AddrType("0")`, you are asking for that member which was added with Key `"0"`. Any string can be used as a key - it's just that the particular string used here is the string representation of a number.

Incidentally, stylistically I would say writing `CStr(0)` rather than `"0"` isn't particularly nice...

Comment: I'd almost think the original programmer tried to use 0 first, and when that didn't work correctly he determined that keys are String.  Then unthinkingly the `CStr()` got tossed in and it was never given another thought.

Answer (score 1):

The CStr() function there is used to access a specific member of the AddrType collection.  Collections can be referenced either by a numeric index or by a string key value.  So the short answer is, integers **don't** have to be converted to strings to access collection members.  Why this particular coder chose to use "0" for a key value is unknown; it's certainly no more descriptive than using a numeric index, which would be the only advantage to the string key value.